# Find product Attributes name in shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am add a shipping method. How can find product Attributes name in shipping method.

```
<?php 
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                    $item_data = $cart_item['data'];                        
                        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;                  
                         Getting "Quantity:" product attribute
                        $myAttribute = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'Quantity:', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
                        echo $myAttribute . '<br>';
                     // $attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();
                    //  $name = $attribute->get_name();                     
                } ?>
```

But $myAttribute and $name both not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $attributes = $_product->get_attributes();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($attributes);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gaurav if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.